# Why OpenOnload extensions API for zero-copy doesn't have anything for UDP send or TCP receive?

Tags: c++, zero-copy, openonload

According the OpenOnload Extensions API documentation zero-copy APIs don't include UDP send and TCP receive scenario. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got response from solarflare, the scenario of receiving tcp and sending udp does not have as high a demand as receiving udp and sending tcp.